# Use tabs instead of space in VSCode when writing Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, indentation

How does one make the formatter in VSCode use tabs instead of spaces for indentation when programming in Python? I have already set VSCode to use tabs, but the formatter for Python ignores that and just does its own thing.

I've been trying to Google around, but I am only seeing results telling me how to do the opposite, ie. spaces instead of tabs, but that is not what I want. I tried to look at autopep8, which VSCode seems to be using for this formatting, but I can't find anything useful there, either.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but it's a good idea to follow PEP8 if possible - one of the things that suggests is four-space indents.

Comment: @paxdiablo Ive read that too. With respect any coding language that tells me how to indent with spaces instead of tabs is overstepping just a little.

Comment: @Manngo, there is a rationale to the suggestion, it wasn't just Guido being obnoxiously dictatorial :-) Think of what happens when you `cat` or print your file to a device that has different tab stops than your editor. The code is likely to look quite screwy, *particularly* if you use tabs to line things up in places *other* than the start of the line. And keep in mind PEP8 is coding guidelines, not rules - I think it tries to make that clear. FWIW, we use `black` nowadays and its best feature is that it's not configurable. This has cut down on all sorts of arguments within the teams :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the editorconfig extension.

Create a `.editorconfig` at the root of the project and specify your configuration.

```
root = true

[*] # extensions of the files
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2
```

Run `format document` after that and.. viola!

Comment: I have already set VSCode to use tabs, I don't need another extension to configure that setting. The issue is that the Python-formatter seemingly ignores that setting.